# Should I be concerned about white patches on my tomato?

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

I have a tomato plant that needed to be re potted and cut back because it was stressed. It has recovered really well, but it has a couple of leaves with varying levels of white patches on them now. Is it something I should worry about and if so how do I treat it?
[image]

I also have a dwarf cherry tomato plant I bought that was fairly advanced and it too has the white patches starting on it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks very much like powdery mildew. I would remove the two branches as the rest of the plant looks healthy. Then, spraying a fungicide on the plant is probably a good first step.

Since it is potted, isolate the plant from the others. If you have other tomato plants, spray them as well.