# Why is my dill looking pale

Tags: diagnosis, dill

My dill seems to have a whitish coating most of it. It looks almost powdery and gives it a pale bluish hue.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it needs watering, apart from the mildew - there is a connection between dryness at the root and susceptibility to powdery mildew.

Comment: I damaged this plant a week or so ago. This photo is just after I cut the damaged sections off. More than half the plant. I tried to get it to stop overhanging the pot and support it in a more upright position and heard several cracks as I did so. :( As for watering, this is the driest they have been in a long time. You helped me with my mould problem 3 or so months ago telling me my plants need more space for air flow to dry out a little (fungus problem in my oregano). That did work, but we have had a mild/wet/overcast winter here which took a long time to have the damp go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [your other question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/should-i-be-concerned-about-white-patches-on-my-tomato) into account as well, you have an infestation of powdery mildew in your garden - and your dill is almost covered with it.

As we are talking about edible plants, I strongly suggest you [spray with dilluted milk](https://www.growveg.co.uk/guides/using-milk-to-prevent-powdery-mildew/) before grabbing a "chemical" fungicide.

We have a bunch of questions and answers on the topic, the poster here [has a similar problem](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23495/is-powdery-mildew-spreading-through-my-garden), and our search site gives [this list](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=Powdery%20mildew).

Comment: I thought it might be that. I just got rid of it from my rosemary plants. But it's on a few plants now.